# IdentityServer4 using .NET Framework 4.5.2 in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, identityserver4

how to use IdentityServer4 using .NET Framework 4.5.2 in ASP.NET MVC 5 (not ASP.NET Core). Any example or tutorial will be helpful. I follow the IdentityServer3 but lots of missing components.

I ask this question because I cannot find some example. Actually, I already build the entire application based on .NET Core. However, last minute call, the client not allowing to use .NET Core on the production server. And I have to stick with ASP.NET MVC using .NET Framework 4.5.2 as per requirement.

Comment: read this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49041098/3189412

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IdentityServer4 is ASP.NET Core only. You can use IdentityServer3 for the Katana/MVC5 combination.

https://leastprivilege.com/2017/01/15/platforms-where-you-can-run-identityserver4/