# Web Api .net framework 4.6.1 and identityServer4

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, identityserver4

Web Api .net framework

I have an authentication service done with IdentityServer4 .net core 1.1.
The client settings are as follows:

```
new Client
{
    ClientId = "client",
    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,

    ClientSecrets = 
    {
        new Secret("secret".Sha256())
    },
    AllowedScopes = { "api1" }
},

// resource owner password grant client
new Client
{
    ClientId = "ro.client",
    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPassword,

    ClientSecrets = 
    {
        new Secret("secret".Sha256())
    },
    AllowedScopes = { "api1" }
},

// OpenID Connect hybrid flow and client credentials client (MVC)
new Client
{
    ClientId = "mvc",
    ClientName = "MVC Client",
    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials,

    RequireConsent = true,

    ClientSecrets = 
    {
        new Secret("secret".Sha256())
    },

    RedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5002/signin-oidc" },
    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5002/signout-callback-oidc" },

    AllowedScopes =
    {
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
        "api1"
    },
    AllowOfflineAccess = true
},

// JavaScript Client
new Client
{
    ClientId = "js",
    ClientName = "JavaScript Client",
    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
    AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,

    RedirectUris = { "http://localhost/web/main.html#/redirectLogin#" },
    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost/web" },
    AllowedCorsOrigins = { "http://localhost" },

    AllowedScopes =
    {
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
        "api1"
    },

    RequireConsent = false
}
```

I have a front-end application with javascript using oidc-client. 
In it I can authenticate to the authentication server with the following settings:

```
var userManagerConfig = {
    authority: "http://localhost:5000",
    client_id: "js",
    redirect_uri: "http://localhost/web/main.html#/redirectLogin#",
    response_type: "id_token token",
    scope: "openid profile api1",
    post_logout_redirect_uri: "http://localhost/web",
};

var userManager = new Oidc.UserManager(userManagerConfig);
```

I also have an api web made in .net framework 4.6.1.
In it I want to receive authentication from the front end and use the authentication server to validate the access.

How should the settings be made for this case?

Answer (score 5):

Your API should be registered as an API Resource in Identity Server. Then - it should implement the OwinStartup and have this in it:

```
 public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // accept access tokens from identityserver and require a scope of 'api1'
        app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Authority = "<ids address>",
            ValidationMode = ValidationMode.Both,

            RequiredScopes = new[] { "myapi" }
        });

        // configure web api
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }
```

And, because it is a .NET Framework API, it needs to reference `IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation`. This should not bother you and cause any concerns. It deals with IdentityServer4 tokens with no hesitation.

Everything else is standard - you need `AuthorizeAttribute` on all controllers/methods that you want to require or add this:

```
        // require authentication for all controllers
        config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
```

In the `Startup.cs` and force authorization on all controllers.

Comment: I have also this issue. I try your solution, but the api client works well only with IdentityServer3. Using IdentityServer4 it responds `No actions matched the current request. Route values: ["controller=connect", "action=accesstokenvalidation"]` because the endpoint is not implemented in IdentityServer4

Comment: Thanks for this. I've been stuck on this forever! `ValidationMode.Both` did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

@m3n7alsnak3's answer is correct, i use `app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication` method, but i get unauthorize message!

My webapi is .net 4.6.1 and my IdentityServer4 is .Net Core 3.1.

After two days R&D and read `IdentityServerBearerTokenValidationMiddleware` source code, i found this articles:

[Need to set IdentityServerOptions.AccessTokenJwtType](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/3705)

[Need to set IdentityServerOptions.EmitLegacyResourceAudienceClaim](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/3668)

Finally i add this options in my `IdentityServer` config and it work fine.

```
var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(option =>
        {
            option.AccessTokenJwtType = "";
            option.EmitLegacyResourceAudienceClaim = true;
        })
        .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.Apis)
        .AddInMemoryClients(Config.Clients);
```

Comment: I am trying the same thing but getting an Unauthorized error. Can you share your configuration?